# ChromeDriver not Launching

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I had Selenium + ChromeDriver running fine a few days ago. Idk what happened but now ChromeDriver won't launch. I did not update chromeDriver or Selenium or any other packages besides the Python code I was using to launch chromeDriver but even then it shouldn't affect ChromeDriver. The code in question looks like this:

```
print('Launching Chrome')
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=self.extensions)  # Code never seems to execute past this line
chrome.set_page_load_timeout(300)
chrome.implicitly_wait(3.25)
wait = WebDriverWait(chrome, 90)
print('Chrome Launched Succesfully')
return chrome, wait
```

When I run it I get the message "Launching Chrome" but even after waiting for hours I never get the "Chrome Launched Successfully" message. I'm on ChromeDriver 2.39 for Linux, and I just updated my Google Chrome Stable installation on Ubuntu but the update did not fix it. Like I said this was launching just fine a few days ago with the same version of chromeDriver installed. Is there any way I can get more information about what the problem is or any sort of fix I could use?

When I launch JUST chromeDriver from the command line using 'chromedriver' I get the following output:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.39.562737 (dba483cee6a5f15e2e2d73df16968ab10b38a2bf) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
```

Followed by a blank terminal line of text. I'm not sure if this indicates a problem with my chromeDriver installation or not. 
Thanks!

EDIT: Extensions is created like so:

```
self.extensions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
self.extensions.add_extension(str(os.getcwd()) + '/3.12.21_0.crx')
requests.get('https://app.myextension.com/ajax/check-session')

self.extensions.add_argument('--start-maximized')
```

Comment: Chrome driver 2.39 supports Chrome v66-68. Which version is your chrome browser currently on?

Comment: I am on v67.0.3396.62 (output from google-chrome --version)

Comment: Can we see the options in `self.extensions`?

Comment: Just added it to the original question. It's just one chrome extension I've had no problem loading in the past as well as an argument to start chrome maximized.

Comment: Can you report back if the code is working after removing the chrome_options argument?

Comment: It's been 5 months since you posted the question, did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
self.extensions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
```

Add this option to chrome driver. I hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setHeadless(false);
return new ChromeDriver(options);
```